# Scale object and preserve proportions

Tags: modeling

I want to scale a copy of the small star (the big star) but I want the proportions to remain the same. As you can see the bigger star is thicker. I want them to have the same thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

- Create your star (10 vertices cylinder, scale 5 of them). Extrude it with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Region (Vertex Normals)*. Click the *Offset Even* option in the operator panel (bottom of the *T* panel in 2.9, bottom left box in 2.8).

[image]

- Delete the faces with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces*.

[image]

- Extrude all and again with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Region (Vertex Normals)* and click the *Offset Even* option. You could as well use the *Solidify* modifier.

[image]